# makeBoundHelper alternative in Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I've been injecting Google DFP ads in my blog-posts by using a bound helper so far. Since all Handlebars APIs have been removed in Ember 2.0 **what can I use as of Ember 2.0 instead?**

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(value, options) {

  var parsedHtml = Ember.$('<div />').html(value)

    // Push the ads after the divs have been rendered
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
      googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-111111111-0'); });
    }) 
  }

  return parsedHtml.html()
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use the [Ember.Helper.helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html#method_helper) syntax:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Helper: { helper }, run: { schedule }, $ } = Ember;

export function helperName(params, hash) {
  let parsedHtml = $('<div />').html(params[0])

    // Push the ads after the divs have been rendered
   schedule('afterRender', function() {
      googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-111111111-0'); });
    }) 
  }

  return parsedHtml.html();
}

export default helper(helperName);
```

Params is an array of all the values that you pass to the helper in your template such as `{{my-helper val1 val2 val3}}` `params[0]` is `val1` and so on, the hash is an object containing all the properties you set on the helper `{{my-helper val1 val2 property1=myPropValue}}` and you would access it via `hash.property1`.

Comment: This works great and also thanks for the description

Comment: One more question. Why are you using constants: `const { Helper: { helper }, run: { schedule }, $ } = Ember;` ?

Comment: This is called object [destructuring](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/), ember-cli comes packed with babeljs which allows us to use ES6(ES2015)  syntax, basically what this does is define `helper = Ember.Helper.helper;` it's usage here is purely aesthetic + helps avoid having to use `Ember.` each time.