# Use Handlebars in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use a custom helper in my Ember project. So I have done

```
bower install --save handlebars
```

and then under helpers\compare.js, I have

```
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';

Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function (lvalue, rvalue, options) {
}
```

Is this the correct way to import Handlebars js and use it inside helper ?

### Update

I am now getting:

> Assertion Failed: Helpers may not be used in the block form, for example {{#my-helper}}{{/my-helper}}. Please use a component, or alternatively use the helper in combination with a built-in Ember helper, for example {{#if (my-helper)}}{{/if}}.

I want to use the following

```
{{#compare model.someCount 0 operator = ">"}}
```

Comment: Above is giving error...Could not find module `handlebars`

Comment: I think this has changed so much in the last few months... which version of Ember and Ember-CLI are you using?

Comment: You don't need to add handlebars it's already there, depending on the version of ember you're on it has been augmented/replaced by htmlbars. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988475/makeboundhelper-alternative-in-ember-2-0/31988844#31988844

Comment: I am using Ember v1.13 & CLI version 1.13.x

Comment: I am now getting 
"Assertion Failed: Helpers may not be used in the block form, for example {{#my-helper}}{{/my-helper}}. Please use a component, or alternatively use the helper in combination with a built-in Ember helper, for example {{#if (my-helper)}}{{/if}}."

Comment: I want to use the following 
{{#compare model.someCount 0 operator = ">"}}

Comment: Take the time to read naming conventions and understand errors, the error message is beyond descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Here's a JSBin showing how you would use a component to accomplish this instead of a helper, since block helpers aren't really supported in generated helpers: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puminocuva/edit?html,js,console,output. Keep in mind components need to be named with a `-` in them, which is why I named it `my-compare` and not just `compare`

---

The docs are pretty straightforward on creating helpers: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/writing-helpers/

If you're using Ember CLI 1.13.x with Ember 1.13, I'm not sure how that file above was generated. You should use `ember g helper compare` in your Ember CLI console to create files.

If you find yourself needing to make comparisons in your view, then I would think you'd want your logic to be in the controller and just generate a computed property such as:

```
// some/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  // (...)
  countGreaterThanTen: computed('model.count', ()=> {
    return this.get('model.count') > 10;
  }),
  // (...)
});
```

and use `{{#if countGreaterThanTen}} stuff here {{/if}}` in your template rather than perform complex logic in there via helpers.

**Update**
Also, your error is because you're trying to use a helper with an opening block (that's what the `#` is). When using your own helper in a template, you would just use `{{compare}}` and not `{{#compare}}`.

Comment: Thx...so {{compare}} is also valid and how do I end it ?

Comment: I put an update at the top of my answer with a link to a JSBin. You should use a component instead of a helper if you need a block helper.