# Handlebars RegisterHelper with Ember Error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, registerhelper

I'm pretty lost after trying numerous different things. I am building an Ember site and inside of one of my Handlebars templates, I want to display a link only if a condition is true. Here is my template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="project">
    <div class="project-container">
        {{is_external model.url model.title}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Now, my registerHelper in my js file:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('is_external', function(url, title, options) {
  if (url.indexOf("codepen") < 0) {
      return "<p class='view-external-link'>"+
            "<a href='{{url}}'' aria-label='View {{title}}'' target='_blank'>Visit Site</a>"+
            "</p>";
  }
});
```

The error I keep receiving however, is:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isHelperFactory' of undefined** coming from my ember.js file.

Ideally, I would prefer to just return true or false from the helper to keep the Html out of my helper function but first I just need some help getting it working.

I am including ember, ember_compiler, and handlebars on my page as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [makeBoundHelper alternative in Ember 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988475/makeboundhelper-alternative-in-ember-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of Ember is that since even 1.x, Ember included its own instance of Handlebars, so your external instance might be interfering.

The [Ember v2.2.0 documentation on templates](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/writing-helpers/) says to use `Ember.Helper.helper`, as does v1.13.0. Maybe give that a try and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your Ember?

When i generate helper Ember uses syntax like this

```
import Ember from "ember";

// http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select

export function checkEquality([leftSide, rightSide]) {
    return leftSide === rightSide;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(checkEquality);
```

In the template

```
{{is-equal item.selection selection}}
```

And if you want to use html within helper

you need to return

```
yourHtml.htmlSafe();
```